# How to access $routeParams from protractor tests

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I page for user profile with the following url /#!/people/user/134 
I am trying to create a test that verifies that the data presented on the user profile page are the correct ones. To do that I want to get the user id (134) from the $routeParams and then make a call to the rest endpoint and verify the model against the response of the rest endpoint.

I've tried to find a way to get the routeParams but all the examples I found were hardcoding it... 
The example from the official phonecat tutorial:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $routeParams, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/xyz.json').respond({name:'phone xyz'});

    $routeParams.uuid = 'xyz';
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneCatContr', {$scope: scope});
}));
```

Is there any way I can access the actual routeParams?

Comment: Why not simply get it from the URL? You can use {{browser.getCurrentUrl()}} then parse the string for the param you need.

Comment: If there is an angular way to do it (getting it through $routeParams or something else) I would prefer it - parsing it would probably be my last approach

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that should be solved on the `protractor` side; `protractor` is an end-to-end *high-level* *black-box* testing framework which main purpose is to mimic the real user's interactions with a page in the browser.

But, to follow @adamK's suggestion, you can extract it from the current URL:

```
var url = browser.getCurrentUrl();
var userID = url.match(/(\w+)\.json/)[1];
```

Demo:

```
> var s = "phones/xyz.json";
> s.match(/(\w+)\.json/)[1];
"xyz"
```